# Update attribute from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an app in Ruby on Rails to store played football games.

Each user has to join or create a league to keep the scoreboard private between friends.

When creating a league I want the creator to autojoin the created league.

Controller:

```
class LeaguesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

     def index
         @leagues = League.all

    end

    def new
        @league = League.new

        @user = User.new
    end

    def show

        @users = User.where(:league_id => current_user.league_id)

        find_league

    end

    def create

        @league = League.new(league_params)


        @league.league_admin_id = current_user.id

        find_user


        update_attribute(:user, @league.id)

        @user.save(user_params)

        if @league.save

            redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Successfully created a league"
        else
            render 'index'
        end
    end

    def edit
        find_league
    end

    def update
        find_league

        if @leagues.update(league_params)

            redirect_to @leagues, :notice => "Successfully editted this league!"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
end




private
    def find_league
        @leagues = League.find(params[:id])    
    end

    def find_user
        user = User.find(current_user)    
    end

    def league_params
        params.require(:league).permit(:league_name, :league_admin_id, :join_key, :league_rules)
    end

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:league_id)
    end



end
```

So in the create action I'm looking for the current_user trough the private method find_user, then I'm updating the field league_id and then I'm saving this value. However when creating a new league the autojoin didn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :games
    has_many :multiplayergames
    has_many :users

    belongs_to :league_admin, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'league_admin_id'

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :league

    has_one :league_admin, class_name: 'League', foreign_key: 'league_admin_id'
end
```

Comment: what holds in @user for show action

Comment: It shows all your friends in that league...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `create` action should look like below:

```
def create
    @league = League.new(league_params)
    if @league.save
       current_user.update_attributes(league_id: @league.id)
       redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Successfully created a league"
    else
        render 'index'
    end
end

private

def league_params
    params.require(:league).permit(:league_name, :league_admin_id, :join_key, :league_rules).merge(league_admin_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: This is not working :( Any other advice?

I've allready tried to do it like this :
` @user = User.find(current_user)
        
        @user.update_attributes(league_id: @league.id)`

Comment: @LouisDeBeule can you post what is the association between `User` and `League` ? Is your `League` getting created with the current `create` action ?

Comment: I've updated my question with the association, and yes the league is created in the create action.